# Как добавить информацию на страницу, но не показывать ее?

Tags: javascript, html

На странице (html) выводятся события календаря в виде div, данные получаю по REST через ajax. Хочется сделать, чтобы по клику на каждое событие всплывало окно с более подробной информацией, ее тоже можно получать через ajax. Но для ее получения нужны id уже выведенных событий и может какая-то дополнительная информация, типа времени и даты. Где можно хранить эту информацию? Есть вариант с SessionStorage и LocalStorage, но интересует, есть ли еще способы. Действуем всего лишь в рамках одной страницы, хочется привязать какой-то набор невидимых атрибутов к каждому div или вроде того.

Comment: сделайте invisible элементы

Comment: А хранить информацию в этих элементах в виде строк? Типа JSON туда записать.

Comment: ну да, например.

Comment: конечно нет.... json можно хранить в js. а в нивидимых элементах лучше хранить готовые окна

Comment: добавь лучше атрибуты типа data-id

Comment: eri, про атрибуты - супер, буду смотреть в этом направлении (напиши как ответ, отмечу). Про JSON в js тоже ок =) Очевидная вещь, но что-то вылетело из головы.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно хранить в переменной внутри JS компонента/контроллера.

В самом крайнем случае, можно создать новое поле объекта window, типа

```
window.calendarItems = [ { id: 1, name: 'a'}, { id: 2, name: 'b'}, { id: 3, name: 'c'} ];
```

после чего оно станет доступно везде

```
function clickHandler(idx) {
    server.post(calendarItems[idx]);
}
```

**но это плохая практика.**